# Not able to trim the string which is fetched from mysql db and insert into another table using jmeter

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, beanshell

I am not able to trim the string which is fetched from mysql db and insert into another table using jmeter

In Jmeter, using JDBC request I am able to fetch data from database. In my table there are 2 coloumns. One is a data coloumn and other is ID. My requirement is I want to retreive all data(which is a string with comma seperated) and need to trim the data based on comma seperation.
For eg: "=XXXXIoT2?data=$XXXX,P10,999194446131444,20170308170009,14,1"
Then these trimmed strings need to be inserted into seperate coloumns of a table. How can i acheive this? Kindly help me

Comment: In this string "=XXXXIoT2?data=$XXXX,P10,999194446131444,20170308170009,14,1", which is ID?

Comment: If the ID is 1, you can use below snippet.

String mystring = "=XXXXIoT2?data=$XXXX,P10,999194446131444,20170308170009,14,1";
String[] aftersplit = mystring.split(",");
System.out.println(aftersplit[aftersplit.length-1]);

Comment: Thank you. It works

Answer (score 0):

If the ID is 1, you can use below snippet to retrieve the ID.

```
String mystring = "=XXXXIoT2?data=$XXXX,P10,999194446131444,20170308170009,14,‌​1"; 
String[] aftersplit = mystring.split(",");
System.out.println(aftersplit[aftersplit.length-1]);
```